# PHP social network block feature

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been making a social networking platform, and I've recently been trying to implement a feature that allows people to block other users. What I'm struggling to do is to implement it.

My database has a table called 'blocks' that has two columns: 'userId' being the user that has blocked the other user, and 'blockedUserId' that is the user's id that has been blocked. I want to select all the users that the user has blocked from a table called 'user' and the blockedUserId will be used to select the account that the user has blocked using the 'id' column in the user table.

Another problem I have is implementing a feature where if a user tries to visit a user's profile that has been blocked from them seeing it.

I've got the following code that is nested within a class. The function is intended to show the user on their profile page the people they've blocked.

```
public static function BlockedUsers($_userInfo, $main) {
        // Show user the users they've blocked.
        $userId = $_userInfo['userId'];
        if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($main, "SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE userId='$userId'")) > 0) {

            $query = mysqli_query($main, "SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE userId='$userId'");

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

                $buid = $row['blockedUserId'];

                $query = mysqli_query($main, "SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE blockedUserId='$buid' and userId='$userId'");

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

                    $uid = $row['blockedUserId'];

                    $query = mysqli_query($main, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$uid'");

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        echo $row['username'];
                    }

                }

            }

        } else {
            echo "You haven't blocked anyone yet. ";
        }
```

My account id is 1 and there's other IDs: 2, 3, 4 -- for example. Each of those IDs are associated with a username. Those IDs would be in the table column 'blockedUserId' in the 'blocks' table. The 'blockedUserId' in the 'blocks' table should be used to select all the users in the user table using that id in relation to the 'id' column in the 'user' table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it and add some sample code and data

Comment: To select all blocked users of user id 1234, use this: `SELECT blockedUserId FROM blocks WHERE userId=="1234"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be easily solvable with a nested SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE userId IN (SELECT blockedUserId FROM blocks WHERE userId==1)
```

This does the following: The query in the brackets will collect all blocked user ids corresponding to the given user id (1 in this case). The total query will select all data from the user table where the userId is contained by the result of the Subquery.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go and try to implement this solution.

Comment: A join might be better than a subquery.

Comment: I never use SQL, so I just said what I knew. Feel free to correct my answer. I might  learn something new here aswell.

Comment: List of blocked users:
`SELECT user. * FROM blocks INNER JOIN user ON blocks.blockedUserId = user.id WHERE blocks.userId = 1`

Check if the user is blocked:

`SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE userId = $ profile_user_id AND blockedUserId = $ visitor_user_id`